# Creating an array reference to hash values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Is it possible to return a hash's values as an array reference?

```
\@{values %hash}
```

I looked over the perlref document, but didn't see anything relating to this (or if I did, I wasn't able to relate it to my question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
my $values_ref = [ values %hash ];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.